# WPF Themes and Converters

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application which supports multiple color schemes (i achieve this by swapping Black.Xaml and White.XAML files at run-time, where both have brushes with same key, and then access them using DynamicResources).

Now i have to show **Red** for values **below 0** and **green** for values **above 0**. (i have different green and reds for each themes). So my converter goes like this

XAML

```
<Converters:PositiveNegativeConverter x:Key="PositiveNegativeConverter" DownColor="{DynamicResource RedPrimaryBrush}" UpColor="{DynamicResource GreenPrimaryBrush}" NormalColor="{DynamicResource BluePrimaryBrush}"/>
```

Converter

```
 public class PositiveNegativeConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    #region DependencyProperty

    public SolidColorBrush UpColor
    {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(UpColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UpColorProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for UpColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UpColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UpColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(PositiveNegativeConverter), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public SolidColorBrush DownColor
    {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(DownColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DownColorProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DownColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DownColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DownColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(PositiveNegativeConverter), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public SolidColorBrush NormalColor
    {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(NormalColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NormalColorProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for NormalColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NormalColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(PositiveNegativeConverter), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion

    #region IValueConverter

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            double dblValue = (double)value;

            if (dblValue > 0)
            {
                return UpColor;
            }
            else if (dblValue < 0)
            {
                return DownColor;
            }
        }

        return NormalColor;
    }
}
```

But When i Change the theme on run-time,  i don't get the converter get hit or even my brush properties in the converter get changed (eg: white specific green is not getting changed to black specific green), So how can i achieve an acceptable result.

All other scenarios without converters are working well.

Comment: You can provide a dedicated class `ThemeManager` where you can have event rised when current theme is changed. Then view can subscribe to it (subscribing can be moved to attached behavior if you enjoy MVVM concept) and update bindings (`PropertyChanged("")` or reassigning `DataContext`). There is no other way, you have to trigger "PropertyChanged" event or handle bindings yourself. Converter is called only after that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried without use a DependencyObject combine with a IValueConverter ?